# How to integrate image upload option in jodit editor

Tags: php, editor, wysiwyg, codeigniter-4, jodit

I am trying to integrate Jodit edit in my Codeigniter 4 project,

I have this Js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('textarea').each(function() {
        var editor = new Jodit(this, {
            uploader: {
                url: 'public/connector/upload.php?action=fileUpload'
            },
            filebrowser: {
                ajax: {
                    url: 'public/connector/upload.php'
                }
            }
        });
        editor.value = '<p>start</p>';
    });
</script>
```

But I am not getting a good result, I can't upload, I can't access the elfinder,

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your setting jOedit

```
filebrowser: {
                ajax: {
                    url: 'public/connector/upload.php'
                }
            }
```

Remplace it with :

```
filebrowser: {
                ajax: {
                    url: <?php print base_url('public/connector/upload.php'); ?>
                }
            }
```

And I hope it will work for you!